# Angular 6 set attribute dynamically generated components globally

Tags: angular, primeng

Working on a Angular 6 and Primeng application. Using a primemng component `p-spinner` all over the application.
This component generates an native component `<input type="text"` and 2 buttons with style class `ui-spinner-button`.

I want to skip the TAB on these 2 generated buttons by setting `tabIndex=-1`.

How can I do that?

Using `Angular 6` and `Primeng 6.x`

Answer (score 2):

You have to go native dom manipulation for your particular case use ElementRef to search the class 'ui-spinner-button' and in ngAfterViewInit() setAttribute to the found elements

Comment: Could you please provide any examples?